# c# events: not firing after second level

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, click

I have searched and tried many things, but I am not able to get the following code to work.  It seems that when i have three button in c#, if I click the first it will fire correctly.  However when I click on the second button, it doesn't work to load the third button.  Goes back to the first.  Events don't seem to go past the first level for some reason.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class testingSandbox : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    boot();
}
public void boot()
{
    firstFunc();
}
public void firstFunc()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("func1");
    Button btn1 = new Button();
    btn1.Text = "btn1";
    btn1.ID = "btn1";
    btn1.Click += new EventHandler(secFunc);
    form1.Controls.Add(btn1);
}

public void secFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("func2");
    Button btn2 = new Button();
    btn2.Text = "btn2";
    btn2.ID = "b2";
    btn2.Click += new EventHandler(thirdFunc);
    form1.Controls.Add(btn2);
    Button btn1 = (Button)this.FindControl("btn1");
    //btn1.Click-=new EventHandler(secFunc);
}

public void thirdFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("func3");
    Button btn3 = new Button();
    btn3.Text = "btn3";
    btn3.ID = "b3";
    btn3.Click += new EventHandler(fourthFunc);
    form1.Controls.Add(btn3);
}

public void fourthFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("func4"); 
    Button btn4 = new Button();
    btn4.Text = "btn4";
    form1.Controls.Add(btn4);
}
```

}

Comment: This is because, When you click on btn1, Page Reloads and boot() function calls up there again.

Comment: Clicking on button displays button 2.  It is when I click button 2 that it goes back to button 1, instead of displaying button 3.  If the page refreshes, why does button two load.  What would be the remedy to this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: This is because, Click Event for btn2 is not set on `Page_Load` or `Page_Init event`, Hence will not fire,

Comment: I don't want to initialize function 2 on page load.  I want function 2 to execute when i click button 1.  This is is what it is doing.  However, when I click button 2,the third function does not fire, it loads function one instead.  I am confused why I would need to set it to page_load, won't that just execute when the page loads as oppose to when I click the button?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET recreates the ENTIRE control tree on every request. The things that you write in .ascx file are translated into a C# code file (you can find them in the `ASP.NET Temporary Files` folder) which creates the controls, and that code is run on every request. In your case however, this happens:

```
Request 1:
    You start out with Button1.
Request 2:
    You start out with Button1. A click event for it is received and processed.
    In the event handler you add Button2. You end up with Button1 and Button2.
Request 3:
    You start out with Button1. A click event for Button2 is received.
    Unfortunately there is no Button2, since the control tree got recreated.
    The event is ignored. You end up with just Button1.
```

Dynamic controls in ASP.NET webforms are hard. You need to manually keep track of what controls were added and recreate them at the start of every subsequent request. ASP.NET does not remember this for you.